# No Ubuntu One sync in my tomboy notes sync preferences

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.10, tomboy

There is no option for ubuntu one in tomboy sync preferences

Here is what i can see :

- Local Folder
- ssh (plugin activated)
- TomboyWeb
- WebDAV

When i try to setup sync with TomboyWeb, the SAVE button is inactive.
Local Folder sync runs well

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Editing the server field will enable the save button for you:

1. Edit server field. (Add a character and remove again)
2. Connect to server
3. Save

This is a known issue with the Tomboy in the released version of 11.10: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/845321

The fix is already waiting to make its way into the proposed queue (version 1.8.0-1ubuntu1.1) and then land as an update.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to enable the "Web Sync Service Add-in" (Preferences, Add-ins tab). Then you will have the "Tomboy Web" in the Service drop down (on the Synchronization tab). The server address needs to be https://one.ubuntu.com/notes/